How to update a Sharepoint Document's metadata using Graph API
Sorry to bother with something like that, I couldn't find an answer to my question anywhere.
I'm currently making a mobile application using Ionic, angular and typescript.
The application has a form which once filled should upload a document to a sharepoint document library (or a list, depending on which one is easier to do) and then update it to add several pictures.
I can manage to create my listItem when I'm using a Sharepoint list, but impossible to upload attachments
I can manage to create my document when I'm using a Sharepoint document library, but impossible to edit metadata.
I'm using a Microsoft Entra ID application with GraphAPI app type permissions "Sites.ReadWrite.All"
I want no interraction from the app user (I don't want my user to log in their microsoft account, which they might not have anyway or won't have access to the list/library)
I tried using axios put method to upload the document, that worked
I tried using axios patch method to update metadata like so :
const uploadResponse = await axios.put(
    `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${this.siteId}/drives/${this.driveId}/root:/${fileName}:/content`,
    fileContent,
    {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${sharepointToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain', // Adapt this to the actual file type
        }
    }
);

const itemId = uploadResponse.data.id; // Récupérer l'ID du fichier uploadé
console.log('File uploaded with item ID:', itemId);

// 2. Obtenez l'item de la liste associée
const listItemUrl = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${this.siteId}/drives/${this.driveId}/items/${itemId}/listItem`;
const listItemResponse = await axios.get(listItemUrl, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${sharepointToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
});

const listItemId = listItemResponse.data.id;
console.log('List item ID:', listItemId);

// 3. Mise à jour des métadonnées du fichier (listItem)
const metadataUrl = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${this.siteId}/lists/${this.listId}/items/${listItemId}/fields`;

const metadata = {
    "TypedeRI": this.ri_type,
    // Ajoutez d'autres champs de métadonnées ici
};

const metadataResponse = await axios.patch(metadataUrl, { fields: metadata }, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${sharepointToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
});

But that didn't work (I'm getting a 400 error, invalid request, when trying to update metadata)
I don't know what I can do more than that...
Thanks in advance
Sincerely
